# How does Adobe Digital Editions work with Kobo's DRM?

Tags: drm, kobo, adobe-digital-editions

In some occasional cases, books purchased from the Kobo store must be read or run through [Adobe's Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/digital-editions.html) software. What is the benefit to this requirement, why use Digital Editions specifically, and what happens in the process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Kobo website](http://www.kobobooks.com/ade):

> **When do I need to use Adobe Digital Editions?**
>
> If you use any of Kobo's free reading apps or a Kobo eReader, you may
>   never need to use Digital Editions at all. Kobo's reading apps and
>   eReader can automatically download most books from the Kobo Store, and
>   update your library with them.
>
> The exceptions are when:
>
> - You want to read **eBooks from another store or from a library** on a Kobo eReader;
> - You buy **Adobe DRM PDFs** from the Kobo Store and want to read them on a Kobo eReader;
> - You want to read books from the Kobo Store on **an eReader from another company**.
>
> In these cases you will need to use Digital Editions to open your
>   books and transfer them to your eReader.
>
> The reason for this is that most eBooks from online booksellers and
>   libraries are protected by Digital Rights Management (DRM). DRM
>   prevents the unauthorized copying or redistribution of eBooks, to
>   protect the rights of authors and publishers. There are different
>   types of DRM, but Kobo supports a version by Adobe. This is why you
>   may need to use Adobe's software, Digital Editions, to open and
>   transfer some eBooks to your eReader.

Also, when you buy a book from the Kobo store, you often receive an `ACSM` file (I have received this type of file often when buying ebooks from the Kobo store for my Sony Reader PRS-650). An `ACSM` file is a license file that Adobe Digital Editions will first verify and then download the appropriate ebook.

**UPDATE** (I should have read further down... they mention the ACSM files on the same page as linked above):

> **Why did I get an ACSM file when I downloaded my book from the Kobo
>   Store?**
>
> Your Kobo eReader can read books in EPUB and PDF format. (A file
>   format is how books are stored on your computer.) If you downloaded a
>   book and received an ACSM file, don't worry – this isn't a problem.
>   The ACSM file is the license for the PDF or EPUB book you bought. To
>   get the book itself you just need to open the ACSM file in Adobe
>   Digital Editions. Digital Editions will verify your license and then
>   download your eBook in either EPUB or PDF format. You can then
>   transfer your book to your Kobo eReader (or another compatible
>   eReader).
>
> You will get a license file if you download a book that is protected
>   by Adobe Digital Rights Management (DRM). DRM prevents the
>   unauthorized copying or distribution of books, to protect the rights
>   of authors and publishers. Most books in the Kobo Store are protected
>   by DRM.

Comment: And how do i do that with no pc?

Comment: @Nana - That is a separate question - it depends on what devices you do have