# What is the hidden file .adobe-digital-editions on my Kobo?

Tags: kobo, adobe-digital-editions

What is the hidden folder `.adobe-digital-editions` on my Kobo? I just did a factory reset, but it is still there. Can I delete this?

Comment: [Related](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/590/how-does-adobe-digital-editions-work-with-kobos-drm). I presume this is something to do with Adobe's DRM. If it's an empty directory then it's probably safe to delete it, but I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kobo's devices are compatible with Adobe Digital Editions. If you have books with DRM, you will need that feature, otherwise you can simply ignore it exists.

[More Detail on Kobo + ADE on their Website](http://www.kobobooks.com/ade)

Comment: I deleted it, and I have not noticed a difference. I have not got DRM books at the moment. If you do a factory reset it will reappear.